# Issue when setting a cell value string with emoji, java dhatim/fastexcel

Tags: java, xml, excel, export-to-excel, fastexport

[image]

Code is executed without error, but when i open the xlsx file i see the following

[image]
[image]

I changed the xlsx file to zip, and opened xl/sharedStrings.xml file 
This symbols where there `&#xd83d;&#xde01`;
Here is sharedStrings.xml

[image]

The file `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><sst xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" count="183" uniqueCount="1"><si><t>&#xd83d;&#xde01;</t></si></sst>`

Comment: This was the package issue